# Right way to keep editing state between different widgets in navgable app

Tags: flutter

I have a MaterialApp with different routes navigating to different widgets.

Let's now assume that the widget for the route "/search" has a search input field.

If I now replace-navigate to "/foo" and back to "/search", the contents of the search input field is lost because the widget behind "/search" was built again from scratch.

What is the right "dogmatic" flutter approach to keep the contents of text editing fields that might disappear and reappear?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, there isn't a "dogmatic" way to keep state in flutter. You have different options and you choose what suits your needs best.
There is [ScopedModel](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/scoped_model), [BLoC](https://medium.com/flutter-io/build-reactive-mobile-apps-in-flutter-companion-article-13950959e381), [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) and others. 
I would suggest watching this [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RS36gBEp8OI) about different state management tools and methods.

Comment: Thanks, I am already using BLoC with RXDart in the app. The question was specific about preserving “uncomitted” edits.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I came to. It creates a wrapper widget around a TextField that handles reading and writing the TextField value to a PageStore.

```
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class StoredTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextField child;

  StoredTextField(
      {@required PageStorageKey key,
      String initialValue,
      FocusNode focusNode,
      InputDecoration decoration = const InputDecoration(),
      TextInputType keyboardType,
      TextInputAction textInputAction,
      TextCapitalization textCapitalization = TextCapitalization.none,
      TextStyle style,
      TextAlign textAlign = TextAlign.start,
      TextDirection textDirection,
      bool autofocus = false,
      bool obscureText = false,
      bool autocorrect = true,
      int maxLines = 1,
      int maxLength,
      bool maxLengthEnforced = true,
      ValueChanged<String> onChanged,
      VoidCallback onEditingComplete,
      ValueChanged<String> onSubmitted,
      List<TextInputFormatter> inputFormatters,
      bool enabled,
      double cursorWidth = 2.0,
      Radius cursorRadius,
      Color cursorColor,
      Brightness keyboardAppearance,
      EdgeInsets scrollPadding = const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      DragStartBehavior dragStartBehavior = DragStartBehavior.down,
      bool enableInteractiveSelection,
      GestureTapCallback onTap,
      InputCounterWidgetBuilder buildCounter})
      : child = TextField(
            key: PageStorageKey(
                "child"), // TextField has its own stored state, so pass a PageStorageKey
            controller: TextEditingController(text: initialValue),
            focusNode: focusNode,
            decoration: decoration,
            keyboardType: keyboardType,
            textInputAction: textInputAction,
            textCapitalization: textCapitalization,
            style: style,
            textAlign: textAlign,
            textDirection: textDirection,
            autofocus: autofocus,
            obscureText: obscureText,
            autocorrect: autocorrect,
            maxLines: maxLines,
            maxLength: maxLength,
            maxLengthEnforced: maxLengthEnforced,
            onChanged: onChanged,
            onEditingComplete: onEditingComplete,
            onSubmitted: onSubmitted,
            enabled: enabled,
            cursorWidth: cursorWidth,
            cursorColor: cursorColor,
            keyboardAppearance: keyboardAppearance,
            scrollPadding: scrollPadding,
            dragStartBehavior: dragStartBehavior,
            enableInteractiveSelection: enableInteractiveSelection,
            onTap: onTap,
            buildCounter: buildCounter),
        super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final controller = child.controller;
    final storage = PageStorage.of(context);
    final value = storage?.readState(context);
    if (value is String) {
      controller.text = value;
    }
    controller.addListener(() {
      storage?.writeState(context, controller.text);
    });
    return child;
  }
}
```